# How to implement a loop in a multi parameters filter in a ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to make a loop in a filter parameters

Hey,
I'm doing a multi filters table. Each column as an input to add a string to filter on.
For each column, I call the parameter name with the filter input in the filter function :`paramN: filter[n]`
Is there a way to make a loop in it so I won't have to write every parameter one by one ?
I have everything I need in an array but I don't know how (if it's possible) to call it in the filter.
Should I use a custom filter ? If so, what would be the syntax, and, would it slow the process ?

Here the code of my filter :

```
<tr ng-repeat="folder in listFolders|
    filter:{param1:filter[1],
            param2:filter[2],
            param3:filter[3],
            ...
            paramN: filter[n]
            } as listVisible
">
```

Here is my array :

```
$scope.parametres=[
  {int:1, libelle:'name1', variable:'param1'},
  {int:2, libelle:'name2', variable:'param2'},
  {int:3, libelle:'name3', variable:'param3'},
  ...
  {int:n, libelle:'nameN', variable:'paramN'}
]
```

Thanks !

Comment: Hi Alice, Maybe instead of trying to do this via a filter, would it be a good idea to do the filtering in the controller or link function and store it in a scope property and then iterate over that scope property using the ng-repeat directive.

Comment: Hi @JonathanDsouza, thanks for your comment.
I'm trying to achieve the filtering from the controller but it's a bit tricky for me. I wanted to use the $filter function (`$scope.filteredData = $filter('filter')(array, { param: "string"});`) but I would need to pass the _param_ name dynamically and cant achieve that. Do you know if it's possible ?

Comment: Hi @Alice, Maybe this points you in the right direction https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#findKey

Comment: I finally manage to do it, thanks for your advice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone someday face the same problem as me :

I made this function in my controller (it's called every time a change is made in the filters inputs via a `ng-change`)

```
$scope.filteringFunction = function(){ 
    var filtered=angular.copy($scope.listFolders);
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.parametres.length; i++){
        if($scope.filter[$scope.parametres[i].int]!==''){
            var filter =$rootScope.toNoCase($scope.filter[$scope.parametres[i].int]);
            var param = $scope.parametres[i].variable;
            filtered = filtered.filter(function (item) {
                return $rootScope.toNoCase(item[param]).includes(filter);
            });
        }
    }
    $scope.listFoldersFiltered=filtered;
};
```

and I changed a bit the ng-repeat (basically remove the filter and change the list `listFolders` to `listFoldersFiltered`)

```
<tr ng-repeat="folder in listFoldersFiltered as listVisible">
```

If someone know an other method to do it, I'm all ears !